# Mutability and getters

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

In the example below, I have a Person class and class B that holds a reference to a Person.

Person has a public foo1 method that can alter its state (it's a mutable object).

Suppose clients of class B want to know the salary, name and email of person object. Should I rewrite the getters from Person class in class B (without providing a getPerson method)? Or maybe getPerson is enough, as people will be able to call getSalary, getEmail and getName on it?

Knowing that Person is mutable, we should ask if we want clients of B to modify that person by calling foo1. We may decide to rewrite Person' getters in B or return a clone of that Person object, so that Person in class B won't be modified.

What about a simpler example, if Person was immutable (there would be no foo1 method in this case)? In B, should I have getPerson (which returns a clone, just in case Person will become mutable at a later point), or rewrite all Person's getters?

```
class Person{
    private String name;
    private int salary;
    private String email;
    //other private fields

    public void foo1(){
        //modify some fields here
    }

    public int getSalary(){
        return salary;
    }
    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }
    public String getEmail(){
        return email;
    }

}

class B{
    private Person person;

    public Person getPerson(){
        return person;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 8):

> Knowing that Person is mutable, we should ask if we want clients of B to modify that person by calling foo1. We may decide to rewrite Person' getters in B or return a clone of that Person object, so that Person in class B won't be modified.

If you do not want clients to modify the returned object, another option is to return an interface type which contains only the getters of Person.

> What about a simpler example, if Person was immutable (there would be no foo1 method in this case)? In B, should I have getPerson (which returns a clone, just in case Person will become mutable at a later point), or rewrite all Person's getters?

No, you should have getPerson() and return a reference to the Person instance. Returning a clone "just in case Person will become mutable at a later point" is a ridiculous case of YAGNI, and adding lots of individual getters a horrible case of code duplication.

Don't overthink. Most of all, strive to make your code *simple*.

Comment: If you do not want clients to modify the returned object, another option is to return an interface type which contains only the getters of Person. - to do this first I'd have to create such an interface, solely for the getters of Person class. And I'd need to do that for any other class like this, so it's a lot of code for a small improvement.

Comment: A small but *important* improvement, I think

Comment: @user4205580: well, it's less code than making lots of pass-through getters. And making a clone also takes some code, and it's also more work at runtime.

Comment: Okay, right. I agree, returning a clone can be misleading - clients of my class might think they can modify the person of B by calling foo1 on it, but what they do is modify a clone, not the original object - which could cause problems.

Comment: from where comes the idea that an interface is "a lot of extra code"? it's like 5 lines of code. I hear people say this all the time, but I never understood it

Comment: @kai: it's still code, and worse, it's code that duplicates structures existing elsewhere. It's definitely something that needs a good reason to justify adding it.

Comment: the interface IS the structure that is then implemented by the class. I don't buy that implementing an interface constitutes duplication of code. there are also obvious benefits such as decoupling and safer interaction between types. I agree that interfaces needs good arguments for why they should look the way they do and that they encapsulate a reasonable unit of functionality, but I don't buy that they violate DRY

Comment: @kai: it's not a matter of you "buying" or "not buying" it - that they represent duplication is simply a fact. When I have a method in an interface and again in a class that implements it, then I now have that method's signature twice, and when I need to change it, I have to change it in two places. This doesn't matter when the interface actually represents a meaningful abstraction, but it is a strong argument against the practice of having interfaces for all classes (or all classes of certain kinds, like entities or services) when there is only a single implementation for nearly all of them.

Comment: that's debatable. forwarddeclaring a method and implementing a method might require you to write out the signature twice, but they are two fundamentally different things. if you are changing an interface, you are making a breaking change for every client of that interface, and yes, your implementations might break too. you will have to change your code in several places, that doesn't mean you violated DRY. I'd also note that in a language like Java you *won't* need to change the signature in "both places", since you're likely using some sort of IDE.

Comment: @kai: as I said: it's not an argument against having interfaces, it's an argument against having pro forma interfaces that have only a single implementation and do not represent an abstraction. In that case there is no useful conceptual distinction between the two, and changing the interface and changing the implementation are not really "fundamentally different things" either.

Answer (score 6):

Your design of `B` is **wrong** when it leaks `A`.

This clearly violates the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) and results in [Train Wreck Code](https://thomassundberg.wordpress.com/2011/12/30/how-many-train-wrecks-are-lurking-in-your-code/).

Your intention for *composing* an object is to extend its *knowledge* or *behavior*: Say you want to build a car, the car needs an engine. so it makes perfectly sense to equip the car with an engine.

As a driver, you want to use the *API* (so to say) of the car, i.e. not interfere with the engine but *drive* the car. The same goes for consuments of your class `B`. The fact, that `B` is composed of `A` should be **unknown** to its consuments.

If an external object needs to know something the `A` within `B` could answer, it should ask `B`.

**Additionally**: If you provide access to `A`, the result is *tight* coupling between the consuments of `B` and `A`, who rely on the implementation of `A` and `B`, which is not, what you want.

Comment: So there should be no getPerson method in B? Other upvoted answers say otherwise (Michael Borgwardt's). And according to your reasoning, I'd have to rewrite Person getters in B.

Comment: I tend to disagree for the above reasons - and I added one more.

Comment: Consider the `Car` class, which holds an `Engine` instance. Let's say engines are made of some parts. If the consumer of Car class wanted to know parts of the engine (it's reasonable he might want that, right?). If Car had a getEngine method, that would be bad, as you explained. So the solution is to 1) provide getPartsList method in Engine class, and 2) provide getPartsList method in Car class as well?

Comment: From the perspective of a consumer of cars it should not be necessary to ask for implemenation details. If you want to know how much fuel an engine needs you read the "car specs" and do not disassemble the car. The need for the knowledge about the implementation details of an object is wrong. Perhaps embedding the one object is wrong in the first place.

Comment: Okay, forget about cars. Let Car be class A, let Engine be class B, and let parts be objects of class C. And again, assume this design is valid. Users of A should be able to know the list of C objects by asking A directly, not getting the B object first and then getting the list out of it. However, as a user of the car, I want to know the parts of the engine, in case something gets broken.

Comment: Perhaps embedding the one object is wrong in the first place. - do you mean the engine shouldn't be part of Car object?

Comment: If you want to observe the engine alone it is pointless to hide it in a car and complain about having no easy access. If you want the state before it is placed inside the car, ask it directly *before* it is entered. You should question your need, why you want to know the state of the embedded object. That is, where the problem arises. Either the need is wrong or the embedding. Maybe both.

Comment: @user4205580 When in doubt imagine how the system would work if it was a real system. You don't ask for car for the engine so you can then manually start it. You ask the car to start the engine, and you don't care how it does it. No client of the car needs to know how the engine start mechanism works, and has no need to getEngine from the Car object. Think about what each object's behaviour is, not what data it holds. Forget about data, data is largely irrelevant. One key design goal of Object Orientated design was to eliminate data completely.

Comment: @CormacMulhall should any method return a List in a well designed OO program? We can't eliminate data completely. Every engine is associated with a Car, and if a car mechanic wanted like to repair it, it should first know what parts the car's engine has. And I'm not sure if there should be two different Car classes in a program, one for the normal driver (without access to the parts) and the other for car mechanic.

Comment: If for some reason the behaviour of the object results in a list it would. But a getter method is not behaviour. A car mechanic analogy doesn't really work because in an OO system the car would simply repair itself. If you are taking data out of objects to work on that data some where else in the system you have a flaw in your design and the first question to ask is is my data in the right object? The easiest way to avoid this is to forget about data completely until you have designed the behaviour of your objects. Then just define the data each object needs to carry out that behaviour.

Comment: Brian Agnew touched on this point above. OO systems have no meaning unless you are discussing the behaviour of the objects, what are they doing. Discussing data without the context of behaviour is putting the cart before the horse. The data only exists to facilitate the behaviour of the objects and the system. Methods that exist only to shuffle data around are not good OO design.

Comment: @user4205580 you could refactor your design, that it follows the inversion of control pattern and makes use of dependency injection. Then you could easily mock the engine and look, what is wrong with the car.

Comment: @CormacMulhall let's say there's a Schedule class. It contains a list of activities (jobs) a person is supposed to perform in a given day. Suppose there are valid schedules and invalid schedules, but the logic of validation obviously shouldn't be placed in the Schedule class itself. And obviously any class that's supposed to validate a schedule should know the list of its jobs. How would you accomplish the validation of objects without accessing the list of jobs from the Schedule?

Comment: The logic should be placed in the schedule class, a schedule should know itself if it is valid or not if it is its responsible to tell the system it is valid. But that logic should be encapsulated in its own object, (eg. a ScheduleValidator) that the schedule can use to determine if it is valid or not. That validator can be passed into the schedule either at initialisation (ie dependency injection) or when the schedule is asked to validate itself. Basically the system says "Hey schedule, validate yourself with this validation rule object" or something like that

Comment: When in doubt think about how you would do this if objects were people. If you had a group of people responsibility for a set of schedules you wouldn't have those people publicly list out all the data of the schedule to another person listening who is responsible for reading in that data and validating a schedule, who then says "Valid" or "Invalid" to each one. Instead the person responsible for each schedule would be handed a set of rules (the same rules for each person) about what is a valid schedule, and they would say "Using these rules I've determined my schedule is valid/invalid".

Comment: I would go as far as saying, that the schedule should refuse any state change which would make it invalid. Nevertheless a) the schedule should validate b) would make use of the strategy pattern to swap out different rulesets.

Comment: @ThomasJunk Yep ideally no behaviour should be able to put the schedule into an invalid state in the first place. I supposed my example was more to illustrate that an object can use other objects passed to it in order to carry out behaviour without that behaviour having to be coded in the class. As they used to say about Smalltalk in OO design everything happens some where else.

Comment: While the overall advice is usually good in this answer, the Law of Demeter has its own problems, and often results in additional code or complexity. I wish people would stop referring to it. It is not a "Law". It is simply an expression of a guideline that is sometimes useful.

Comment: @FrankHileman no the name doesn't reflect its nature. But as a best practice to avoid coupling and help following the information hiding principle it is as good as a law :)

Comment: @ThomasJunk: yes, it does both of those things, and those things can be important. But it has side effects -- lots of forwarding code, which can become a problem in itself.

Comment: @CormacMulhall you suggest to place the ScheduleValidator object inside the Schedule. Okay. And it implies that the Schedule class needs a method that lets others access the list of its jobs, so that scheduleValidator can analyze the schedule and decide if it's valid or not.

Comment: @CormacMulhall Thomas Junk mentioned that no invalid schedules should even exist, that would eliminate the issue of validating/invalidating it completely. What if you had a set of valid schedules, and the rules of validation changed one day? I'd ask you to throw away all that are invalid according to the new rules, and keep the rest.

Comment: @user4205580 No, the validator doesn't access these, it doesn't pull these out of the schedule. The schedule passes them into the validator when it uses the validator object to validate itself. The schedule has the validator object inside it and says "Here, with this data tell if me if I'm valid or not". The scheduler controls what data is passed to the validator. The schedule must know the interface to the validator in oder to understand how to use it, but the validator doesn't need to know anything about the schedule. It just does what it is told.

Comment: @user4205580 In the case of changing validation rules then yes using a validation object is the way to go, since the schedule's structure isn't what determines if it is valid or not. In other objects, where the object is aware of the rules of its own validation, it is better to not let an invalid change take place. For example an invoice that knows it can never have more than 100 records, no method on the invoice should let it add more than 100.

Comment: There are two things to consider: 1) implmenting validation as a ` strategy` for the schedules 2) proactively check, whether a given schedule would be invalid or retroactively checking whether a given schedule is invalid with the current `validation strategy`.

Comment: @CormacMulhall but still, if we pass the list of Jobs to the scheduleValidator, the validator needs to inspect the Job objects somehow, which means the need for getters in the Job class. I don't think getters can be eliminated completely. But I agree that 'tell, don't ask' principle is what we should aim for.

Comment: @user4205580 Generally if you are using a getter there is something wrong with your design, the data is in the wrong place or you are not thinking of as the object as a unit of behaviour. For example there is no reason you can't pass an object into the Job object and allow that object to carry out some action with that object which is then passed on. I don't know exactly what validation system you have in mind, but you should always tell an object to do something (possibly using another object) rather than ask for data out of the object.

Comment: @CormacMulhall right, but you suggested to pass the data of schedule to ScheduleValidator. The data of Schedule is a collection of Job objects. If you pass a collection of Jobs, the validator needs to get information from individual jobs to tell if the schedule is valid. Knowing that we don't want getters, how would you redesign it?

Comment: @CormacMulhall here, we could take the collection of jobs, and pass the validator to each of them using one of Job's methods. Inside that method, the Job would pass its data to the validator. I don' think its okay, since Jobs should be unaware of the fact that schedules might be validated, or there exist validators at all.

Comment: @user4205580 you could use the visitor pattern to implement validation.

Comment: As I understand it, Schedule would have the accept method (that would take the visitor - the schedule validator as the argument), and ScheduleValidator would have the visit method. More or less? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/visitor_pattern.htm

Comment: The question is how to correctly gather the information about Jobs in the Schedule and pass them to the validator using its visit method, without getters. The simplest solution is to create, in the accept method, an empty list containing the data the validator needs, and then for each Job j call j.attachInfo(list). Then we could pass the list to the validator, by calling scheduleValidator.visit(list). I can't simply do scheduleValidator.visit(this), because it would mean the necessity for getters in Schedule class.

Comment: @user4205580 Well again I don't know exactly how the validation is supposed to work so it is a bit difficult to provide a definitive answer. I will say though that don't let your design get constrained by where you think the data should live before you have worked out the behaviour of the objects. If you have an object that only exists to provide getters to some data, that object is unnecessary. That data should be some where else. So the first question I would ask is what is the point of a Job object? Does this do anything other than wrap job data?

Comment: @user4205580 See example below of a quick and dirty example of how to write what we are discussing without needing a getter method on Jobs. You simply add the behaviour to jobs to compare itself to some time, then another job can use that behaviour to compare itself to a job. These methods will survive an internal redesign of the Job object as they don't rely on getting the info out of Job, but rather a utilising the public interface. It is also cleaner design because the behaviour is clear from the methods on Job

Answer (score 3):

What is class `B` *doing*. Remember that OO is about *telling objects to do things for you*. So (for example) if `B` is a `PersonnelManager`, it could have a collection of `Person` objects and work at a higher abstraction level (e.g. `giveRaise(percentage)` ). I wouldn't expect it to proxy those `Person` objects for you (which is what you're implying in some of the above)

The exception to the above would be if `B` was some sort of DAO, but then I don't think your questions above apply at all)

Answer (score 2):

For class B, is the fact that it has a reference to a Person just an implementation detail, or is it part of the spec of class B that it should provide access to a Person object?

That's the question, and the answer decides what interface class B should provide. Could it make sense to change from a reference to Person to a reference to some different class that might be more suitable? If you gave access to a Person, and suddenly you have no Person in class B anymore, you have lots of code changes to make. On the other hand, if that reference to Person is essential for users of class B, then make it available.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on what I was saying in the comments, this is a simple example in Ruby of how you can do what @user4205580 is asking without having to use `getter` methods. For those unfamiliar with Ruby values starting with `@` are private instance variables.

This is a quick and dirty example (writing it in a coffeeshop while waiting for my tea) and I don't claim it is awesome design, but rather a quick proof that in most cases where you think you need a getter a few minutes thinking about it can show that you don't.

```
class Job
  def initialize(name, start_time, end_time)
    @name = name
    @start_time = start_time
    @end_time = end_time
  end

  def starts_before(time)
    @start_time < time
  end

  def starts_after(time)
    @start_time > time
  end

  def conflict?(job)
    job.starts_after(@start_time) && job.starts_before(@end_time) # Test if job starts after we start, but before we end
  end
end


class Schedule
  def initialize
    @job_list = []
    @validators = []
  end

  def add_job(job)
    @job_list << job
  end

  def add_validator(validator)
    @validators << validator
  end

  def valid?
    @validators.all? do |validator|
      validator.run(@job_list)
    end
  end
end


class NoTimeConflictRule
  def run(jobs)
    # FYI product gets combo of every job eg [[1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 1]... etc
    # so we can compare every job to every other job. any? returns true if any
    jobs.product(jobs).each do |job_a, job_b|
      if (job_a != job_b) && (job_a.conflict?(job_b) || job_b.conflict?(job_a))
        return false # We have a time conflict, return false
      end
    end
    true # No conflict so return true for validation
  end
end


clean_shower = Job.new "clean shower", Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 9, 45), Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 10, 45)
walk_dog = Job.new "walk dog",  Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 10), Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 10, 30)
do_homework = Job.new "do homework", Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 11), Time.utc(2016, 06, 12, 12)

invalid_schedule = Schedule.new
invalid_schedule.add_job clean_shower
invalid_schedule.add_job walk_dog
invalid_schedule.add_validator NoTimeConflictRule.new

puts "My invalid schedule is valid? - #{invalid_schedule.valid?}"

valid_schedule = Schedule.new
valid_schedule.add_job clean_shower
valid_schedule.add_job do_homework
valid_schedule.add_validator NoTimeConflictRule.new

puts "My valid schedule is valid? - #{valid_schedule.valid?}"
```

This code runs, and if you do you will get this output

```
$ruby stack_overflow.rb
My invalid schedule is valid? - false
My valid schedule is valid? - true
```

Update - some good books on object orientated design that focus on behaviour

[Object Thinking](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735619654)

[Designing Object Oriented Software](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136298257)

[Business Engineering with Object Technology](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471045217)

[Object Oriented Software Engineering](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201544350)

[Smalltalk, Objects and Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1583484906)

Comment: Just to clarify, is it completely wrong to create classes in OO language like Java, if their sole purpose is to hold data, i.e. using classes as data structures? IMO - not really. I've seen many cases of using a Person class, that just hold information about a given person (and contains getters, of course). How much more mess in the code would there be without Person class in such cases.

Comment: Well nothing is "completely wrong", but it is a design smell, a reason to pause and think. It means you have an object with no behaviour, that exists simply to hold data. The first question would be if the behaviour is some where else why is the data not some where else as well. You don't have to have a Person class just because you have, say, a person record in a database. If your design is being lead by your data rather than by the behaviour of the system then you will end up with a hard to manage system because you will have data leaking between objects.

Comment: Also just because developers do it doesn't mean it is a good idea. Software developers make bad software all the time. So seeing something that is common is not the same thing as seeing something that is good. There are a number of good books that get to the root of object orientated design (behaviour lead development) that I'll append to the answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I will focus on the `foo1()` part of the question.

> Person has a public foo1 method that can alter its state (it's a mutable object).
>
> ...
>
> What about a simpler example, if Person was immutable (there would be no foo1 method in this case)?

I suppose your uncertainty about *whether* `Person` should be immutable reflects your uncertainty about whether `foo1()` should exist on `Person`. In other words, you have the choice of implementing it either way.

Here is an example of how to implement immutable `Person` while allowing a `foo1()` that seemingly has access to some mutable state. My insight is that the "some mutable state" does not need to be stored on the `Person` object.

```
// mutable and contains the additional mutable state
// used by foo1() but is not stored as part of Person.
class Foo
{
    // ...
}

class FooCollection
{
    private HashMap<Person, Foo> mapPersonToFoo; 
}

class Person
{
    public Person(string name, ..., FooCollection fooCollection)
    {
        this.fooCollection = fooCollection;
    }
    public void foo1()
    {
        Foo myFoo = fooCollection.getFoo(this);
        // use mutable foo, as long as it does not modify Person
    }
}
```